# Is it possible in Android (noon rooted) to intercept access to the contact list?

Tags: android, proxy, contacts

I'm curious if it was possible in Android to intercept the Access of an app to the contact list - like a Proxy.

E.g.

1. Whatsapp tries to read the contacts
2. The request is intercepted by the app and passes the request to the
   contact app.
3. The returned contact app is checked by the app
4. The app only returns some of the contacts but not all.

Is such a Scenario possible with a non rooted Android device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, no, this is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.